# Find opposite face of dodecahedron

Tags: geometry

Can anyone tell which one (A,B,C or D) is the opposite face of the face marked in red in the dodecahedron ? What is the best way to find it?

[image: dodecahedron]

Comment: I think it'll be $A$, considering the symmetry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is opposite (B); you can find this by marking the faces adjacent to the red face, and then marking the faces adjacent to those; then the remaining face, (B), is opposite the red face.